# Best way to extends doctrine QueryBuilder class in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I would like to use QueryBuilder with custom shortcut functions.
For exemple:

Instead of write in my repo:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('post')->where(...)->andwhere(...)
```

use something like:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('post')->isPublished()
```

where `isPublished()` is kind of shorcut method for multiple querybuilder functions (`->where(...)->andwhere(...)`)

Thx in advance for your help.

Comment: I would recommend against it. Instead I suggest a method/function `isPublished(QueryBuilder $qb)` its body will call your series of `$qb->where(...)->andwhere(...)`. In this way you can reuse code, which is what I think, you would like to do.

Comment: Like @JanMares says, just create a repository function to do this.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create your repository class like this:

```
<?php

namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class MyRepository extends EntityManager
{

    public function isPublished()
    {

    }
}
```

2) In your controller:

```
$entityManager = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$entityManager->getRepository('MyBundle:MyRepository')->isPublished();
```

Answer (score -2):

I you really want to do that, switch to Eloquent